# Nested Flexbox stretches Image

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm trying to have two nested flexboxes with a centered image in the innermost, that will always fit into its container while keeping its ratio, without ever being stretched. 
The image is fitted with:

```
img{
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Take look here:
https://jsfiddle.net/quz4zgb0/2/.

Here the width is scaled properly, but the height gets stretched as soon as the container gets too small. How can I prevent this?

Thanks in advance!
Jacques

Comment: Looks how you want it on Chrome and FF. I don't see any stretching. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

applying `object-fit: contain;` and `flex-shrink: 0;` to the `<img>` should get you pretty close to what you want.

Comment: This seems to prevent the stretching, but now the height overflows and the image is not scaled at all.

Comment: @jacquesknie see my updated answer. i mean ``object-fit: contain;`` not cover.

Comment: Ah yes, that also works! That might even be the nicer solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

By default, flexbox children has a `flex-shrink` value of 1, which means that, if necessary, the child will shrink to fit as needed.

By adding `flex-shrink: 0` to your `.image-container` element, you'll see that it now scales correctly and uniformly.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers still have troubles with image and flex parent.

Firefox has no bug that i've seen, chrome does and IE 11 is even worse.

While it is not yet coherent through all of them, you may, here, use absolute positionning:

```
.image-container{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
}

.image-container img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
  max-height:100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.main-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header,
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: red;
}
.image-container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="header">header</div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://weknownyourdreamz.com/images/circle/circle-08.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/quz4zgb0/3/